# Can I Bypass both MS Passcode and PIN on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, pin

How can I disable both MS Passcode and PIN on Windows 10?
I am currently required to enter PIN number everytime my PC wakes up from sleep mode.  I changed the Settings in the Sign-in Options to never be required to sign-in again, but it is still asking to enter PIN number every time Windows comes out of sleep.

I hope someone can help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Type `Power options` into Start Menu.
- Click `Require a password on wake-up` in the navigation on the left.
- Windows will disable all the checkboxes on this page by default. To enable click `Change settings that are currently unavailable` near the top.
- Under `Password protection on wake-up` select `Don't require a password`

Comment: Papa, My system was already set that way. The problem is that Windows 10 requires me to enter my PIN # every time it wakes up. My question was HOW DO YOU DISABLE BOTH SO I CAN BYPASS BOTH LAYERS OF LOGIN?

Comment: Did you remove/delete the PIN?